# Flex: Reverse Order of ArrayCollection so that the Last Item Appears First in a ComboBox

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, arraycollection

Is there a way to reverse the order of the items in a comboBox? I'd like to use index numbers to refer to items in the arrayCollection below. I want the newest content to appear first in the comboBox. But, if I add something above the first item then all of the index numbers will be off by one. If I could add a new item to the end of the arrayCollection, but have it appear first in the comboBox drop down that would solve a lot of problems.

```
<mx:ComboBox  id="MyComboBox" change="handler(event);"   prompt="Make a Selection">
    <mx:ArrayCollection id="myDP">
        <mx:Object  id="first" label="Label 1" series="2"  pageTitle="Title 1"/>
        <mx:Object  id="second" label="Label 2" series="7" pageTitle="Title 2"/>                                        
        <mx:Object  id="third" label="Label 3" series="9"  pageTitle="Title 3"/>                                        
    </mx:ArrayCollection>
</mx:ComboBox>
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by adding a Sort to your ArrayCollection.  Here's an example: [Sorting an ArrayCollection using the SortField and Sort classes](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/05/sorting-an-arraycollection-using-the-sortfield-and-sort-classes/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use the method myDP.source.reverse()